# prove $ \int_0^1 (1-x^p)^\frac{1}{q} \,dx = \int_0^1 (1-x^q)^\frac{1}{p} \,dx$

Tags: integral-equations

prove that for every $ p,q \gt 0$

$$ \int_0^1 (1-x^p)^\frac{1}{q} \,dx = \int_0^1 (1-x^q)^\frac{1}{p} \,dx$$

I tried to start from one side and change variables to get something similiar to the right side, but it got my no where.

Comment: Do you know the Beta function?

Comment: I dont know it.

Comment: Inconvenient. Anyway, on the left, you can substitute $t = x^p$, and on the right $u = x^q$. Then you can see whether you get any further from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\int_0^1\,\left(1-x^p\right)^{\frac1q}\,\text{d}x=\int_0^1\,(1-t)^{\frac1q}\,\frac{1}{p}t^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\,\text{d}t$, where $t:=x^{\frac1p}$.  Now, with $u:=1-t$, we get $\int_0^1\,\left(1-x^p\right)^{\frac1q}\,\text{d}x=\frac1p\,\int_0^1\,u^{\frac1q}(1-u)^{\frac1p-1}\,\text{d}u$.  Using the technique of Integration by Parts, we obtain
$$\int_0^1\,\left(1-x^p\right)^{\frac1q}\,\text{d}x=\left(\left.-u^{\frac1q}(1-u)^{\frac1p}\right|_{u=0}^{u=1}\right)+\int_0^1\,(1-u)^{\frac1p}\,\frac{1}{q}\,u^{\frac{1}{q}-1}\,\text{d}u\,.$$
Finally, with $y:=u^{\frac1q}$, we have
$$\int_0^1\,\left(1-x^p\right)^{\frac1q}\,\text{d}x=(0-0)+\int_0^1\,(1-y^q)^{\frac1p}\,\text{d}y=\int_0^1\,(1-y^q)^{\frac1p}\,\text{d}y\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that both integrals measure the area described by the same geometric shape, namely $x^p+y^q=1$.